# Blob-like alien that shoots out tentacles people would stick to

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read a short story in an anthology when I was very young (I'm guessing it was some time in the mid-'70s). All I remember is that there was a blob-like alien of some kind, sitting in the middle of a city, shooting out tentacles that people would stick to, and be drawn into it, I assume to be digested.

Comment: When were you "very young"? Since we don't know how old you are, we don't know when that was.

Comment: Sorry. I'm guessing some time in the mid-'70s.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I edited that into your question. In the future, please [edit] your question itself with new information rather than putting it in the comments. Welcome to SFF.SE!

Comment: Gregg, should you return, don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 4):

Sounds vaguely similar to parts of "The Kraken Wakes" by John Wyndham. Aliens who live at high pressure invade the Earth's oceans, and send tanks on to the coastlines. These tanks shoot blobby tentacles that stick to people, drag them to the tank, and then the whole mass is drawn back into the water as the tank retreats with its captives. What happens to these unfortunates is never revealed.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and helpful response. That may well be it. I'll see if I can get a copy through ABE. Thanks again!

Comment: Just finished The Kraken Wakes and indeed the scene I was thinking of was there. Thanks again for the help!