# Trying to identify a sci-fi story in an anthology from the mid-70s

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, anthology-book

The story appeared in an anthology provided to kids in British schools during 70s.

The story had a very simple structure. It was a description given by a man who was observing a vision of the history of humanity probably from the beginning, and certainly to its end. The history he observed took the form of a long procession of people through the ages. Towards the end the observer watched technology become more and more of an oppressive burden to the humans in the procession. He watched wretched humans carrying huge pyramids that were presumably computers and that burdened them down as they walked forward. They had become slave to their machines. But then finally, at the very end, the last type of humans were freed from machines. They were transformed and danced and had limbs that bent in strange ways. They had something of the animal about them. The procession of the history of humanity ended positively.

The story had an old, perhaps 19th century feel to it, so I wonder if it was an excerpt from Wells or Stapledon, but I can't find any reference.

Edit: I have removed my previous reference to an anthology as I have identified it, and it does not contain the story. See below. The search goes on :(

Comment: According to [ISFDB](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1426), the only anthology that contained *The Kraken Wakes* is one by Alfred Hitchcock named either *Slay Ride* or *Stories That Scared Even Me*, which seems to be horror focused and none of the other stories in it look to be a match.

Comment: Yes, I saw that. It is clearly not Slay Ride. As such, I fear the anthology is not listed in ISFDB. But it certainly existed, as evidenced by the link I provided to the other question referencing it. Is there any other way to track down potential candidates? Perhaps via publisher? It was probably an anthology supplied to schools for students between 7-12 years of age in the UK.

Comment: An excerpt from The Kraken Wakes (American title Out of the Deeps) was published under the name Phase Two: http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1377618 and it appears in this anthology: http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?359199 .However, I don't see the story I am looking for in there.

Comment: Please note, I have removed all references to the anthology in this question as I have identified it and cannot see it in the anthology and it muddies my question. However, I have added the information to another question that pertained to the anthology here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/121589/blob-like-alien-that-shoots-out-tentacles-people-would-stick-to/241729#241729

Comment: I found a copy of [Weirdies, Weirdies, Weirdies](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/83305.Weirdies_Weirdies_Weirdies) and you're correct that nothing in it matches your story.

Comment: Perhaps something by Olaf Stapledon? The description is vaguely reminiscent of *Last and First Men*, except for the positive ending.

Comment: 4 anthologies that I have identified reading reading at school are as follows. But I don't see it in them: Zoo 2000
http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?55915
Space 1-3
http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?3753